# How to repair office DAO? (Or is it my fault excel crashes?)

Tags: excel, vba, dao

I did following: A database connection over vba in excel (DAO) works both in office 356 and 2016. After setting a database password in Office 356 this db cannot be opened over DAO in Office 2016. (both same lib, Office Access 16 database engine object". So I set the password in Office 16, works now. After opening the file in Excel 356 again Excel crashes at an unexpected operation without error message. Now all other DAO connections in all files on this pc do not work anymore. (I think its just a random bug and hasn't anything to do with this password thing)

This error is actually reproducible on this pc.

1. I created a test.accdb and added one table with 2 fields and one record.
2. I created a test.xlsm and added following code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = DAO.OpenDatabase(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/test.accdb")
    Dim ts As DAO.Recordset
    Set ts = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Tabelle1")
    Dim myfield As DAO.field
    If Not ts.EOF Then
        For Each myfield In ts.Fields ' crash here
            MsgBox myfield.Name
        Next
    End If
    ts.Close
    db.Close
End Sub
```

[image]

At exactly this line excel stops existing. Just press F8(next line) and back to desktop. Just away. No error. ts.Fields is not nothing as you can see in image.
I've restarted my system, no change. How to repair DAO database connections? Or is some problem in this code? The same files work like expected on my other pc.

EDIT: As noted correclty it is not wise to call the object "field" as Excel imports the namespace of DAO automatically. The error also occurs when naming it myfield.

EDIT2: The error found in system protocol is somehow unspecific: ACEDAO.DLL 0xc0000005

Comment: Therefore *"The same files work like expected on my other pc"* the error cannot be in the code. Furtherome if your Excel force closes to the desktop this is very likely a bug you run into or a corrupt install. Make sure you update your Windows and Office to the most recent version available on Windows Update. If that doesn't help, reinstalling Office might be an option to try (if no one comes up with a quicker idea).

Comment: Ahh first try to rename your variable `field` just in case you get some weired interference between `field` and `DAO.field`. So `Dim MyField As DAO.Field`. Try never to use reserved words for variable names.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ correct, bad example. Tried to make the example easier to read...  Nevertheless it also happens when I call it field1.

Comment: Well, then it must be something wrong with the install or at least something outside the code. Crash of Excel (without error message) means something horribly gone wrong. So either a bug (compare versions with the computer that works) or bad install is my bet in this case.

Comment: Mmh... the error is caused by ACEDAO.DLL....maybe office reinstall will help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It was an MS Office error which was resolved after office reinstall.